# How do I change the colour and bullet points in a list?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

The link is obviously purple, as usual. I know the code to change the colour of the link, but how do I change the colour of the link that I'm on? Eg: I'm on page 2, how do i change the colour?

Also it's added bullet points (which I don't want) How do I take them off? I've tried:
list-style: none
Which didn't work.

Comment: are you talking about styling `<li>` elements?

Comment: Please include the HTML and CSS you're using so that we can determine where the errors lie.

Comment: This type of question has already been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397370/how-to-change-the-link-color-of-the-current-page-with-css

Answer (score 0):

Usually there will be an additional css class attached to the `<li>` element corresponds to the current page, for example:

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
    <li class="current-page"><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
.current-page a {
    color: red;
}
```

To remove the bullet points from the list, you can apply the following css rule to your list:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```