# CSS link properties when pointing to the currently active page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

Using bootstrap 3 on a drupal site, how can I change the color and weight of links pointing to the currently active page?  I tried using `a:active` but that does not do what I was expecting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the link color of the current page with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397370/how-to-change-the-link-color-of-the-current-page-with-css)

Comment: This is a drupal specific question - the duplicate linked does not match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal is adding an "active" class to the links to the current page.  This is different than setting the property of an `<a>` to "active".  Use the selector `a.active` in your CSS instead of `a:active`.  You should be able to inspect the properties in developer tools to ensure the class being added and how to target it.

Answer (score 0):

On the server-side, you can make it with javascript.

**The theory**

Make a css class with the styles you want (you can name it *.nav-active* or whatever you want.

Then append the class to an element with a javascript click function, here's an example using jQuery.

```
$(".nav-item").click(function(){
    $(".nav-item").removeClass("nav-active");
    $(this).addClass("nav-active");
});
```

Here's a pen so you can see how it works:

http://codepen.io/edfreitas/pen/PqbWbP

Comment: thanks Eduardo, this lesson Im definately taking home with me.