# JQuery .each function and changing CSS for link of current page [explanation]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this thread "[How to change the link color of the current page with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397370/how-to-change-the-link-color-of-the-current-page-with-css/15833068#15833068)" @Taraman writes some neat JQuery function that is praised by others. Now I tried to use his code, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I was busting my brains out to figure out why his code doesn't work for me, but I couldn't figure it out.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain me how his code works and what I'm missing.

Here is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>  <!--Taraman's code-->
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[href]").each(function() {
           if (this.href == window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
                }
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="topnav-bg">
     <div id="topnav">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>  <!--dots mean "www.myurlsomething.com"-->
            <li><a href="../about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="../science.html">Science</a></li>
            <li><a href="../adventure.html">Field trip</a></li>
            <li><a href="../team.html">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="../biblio.html">Bibliography</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is my css code:

```
#topnav-bg      {clear:both; background-color:#FAF7C0; }
#topnav ul      { margin: 10px 0; padding: 3px 0;  }
#topnav ul li   { display:inline; }
#topnav ul li a { padding: 0 9px; font: bold 14px Verdana;  }

#topnav a:link      { color: black; }
#topnav a:visited   { color: black; }
#topnav a:hover     { color: grey;  }
#topnav a:active    { color: blue;  }
#topnav a:focus     { color: blue;  }

.active  { color: blue; font-weight: bold;}
```

So what I would like to achieve with my code is that when I'm on "About" page, link/word About is coloured blue, while others (Home, Science, ...) are black, etc.
This is probably "no-brainer" for some of you, but I'm obviously missing something.
I would like to know what this line `$("[href]").each(function()` does? Should `"[href]"` be changed by something else?
This line `if (this.href == window.location.href)` returns page location, right? So in my case this should be "www.myurlsomething.com/about.html, right?
Taraman is also mentioned something about url parameters `if (this.href.split("?")[0] == window.location.href.split("?")[0]) ...`. What this code does and to what url parameters was he referring? Should I use this?
I know this is a lot of questions, probably stupid questions. But like they say: "There is no such thing, as a stupid question." :)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href` points to the url path that you see at the url navigation bar in the browser.

```
this.href == window.location.href
```

basically checks if the attribute href value is equal to the url. In your case, even though `this.href` returns the absolute path, the chances are they might not be equal.

In order to make it work, you need to find the matching instance of text ( done here through `split()` ) and compare it with the url.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("[href]").each(function() {
       if (window.location.href.indexOf(this.href.split('/')[this.href.split('/').length - 1]) != -1){
              $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
```

Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/so000t49/3/

Comment: This code works and yet there is no color change. Let me explain. in browser I clicked "Inspect" and found out that code works fine, because `class="active"` was added to `<li> </li>` line. However under "Styles" tab style for `.active` was strike-through. On the other hand `#topnav a:visited` and `#topnav a:link` styles where not strike-through which means that color of text remains black. How to fix this?

Comment: Just add !important to the .active css. Here's the fixed version : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/so000t49/6/

Comment: Thank you DinoMyte, it works perfectly. Could you explain to me this part of the code `if (window.location.href.indexOf(this.href.split('/')[this.href.split('/').length - 1]) != -1)`. Thank you!

Comment: Like I mentioned, that the whole idea is to compare just the page name in the url with the anchor link's href. (window.location.href.indexOf(this.href.split('/')[this.href.split('/').length - 1]) != -1) basically splits the url with delimiter '/' and tags the index n-1 where n is the length of the url. This would give you just the page name ( like about.html ) and then you basically check it's occurence using indexOf javascript function in the anchor tag's href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to note that using an attribute as a selector as well as iterating over that is probably not the most efficient approach. You might consider using a class selector or at the very most a tag selector, then caching your anchor elements as a jquery object in a variable and iterating over the variable instead so you traverse the DOM once instead of iterating over the DOM for each a[href] element.