# How to apply styles like hover, selected to this side nav menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have side nav menu but when i apply styles its disturbing other ul and li elements on page, I want to apply hover and selected styles to this nav, can you please share some sample how can do that for just this specific menu

```
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 navleftnavigator" >
       <!-- Sidebar -->
       <nav class="navbar navbar-center" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation" style="border: 1px solid #862828">
           <ul class="nav sidebar-nav ">
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Home</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">About</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Events</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Team</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Services</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Contact</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="https://twitter.com/maridlcrmn">Follow me</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </nav>
       <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
    </div>
```

Comment: To target CSS only to this particular nav, you could have all selectors prefixed with the `id` like so: `#sidebar-wrapper li:hover { ...`.  That assumes that the `id` is unique on the page (which it should be, as that is a rule for `id`s.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a unique className or even an id to your nav element

And then use a unique css selector.

something like:

```css
nav.crazy-class-name-without-duplicates {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

nav.crazy-class-name-without-duplicates > ul > li {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

nav.crazy-class-name-without-duplicates > ul > li > a {
  color: navy;
}


nav.crazy-class-name-without-duplicates > ul > li:hover {
  /* li mouseover */
  background-color: red;
}

a::selection {
  /* a selection */
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 navleftnavigator" >
       <!-- Sidebar -->
       <nav class="navbar navbar-center crazy-class-name-without-duplicates" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation" style="border: 1px solid #862828">
           <ul class="nav sidebar-nav ">
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Home</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">About</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Events</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Team</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Services</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Contact</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="https://twitter.com/maridlcrmn">Follow me</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </nav>
       <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
    </div>
```

Comment: This works fine but how to add hover and selected colors?

Comment: done, check out the edited answer, basically use :hover and ::selection

Comment: oh, selection is meant to be used at the top level, sorry about that, I just edited my answer again

Comment: works for me, run the snippet and try selecting the code.

Comment: or you mean visited links?

Comment: i want to show different color when user is click on that menu item .

Comment: you'll need javascript for that, this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51557550/3424011

Comment: Thank you @rubentd