# Border full with but then different color for each item

Tags: html, css

Im trying to have a layout like this, with a full width gray border but then below the active item have a different border color:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Em3.png)

But its not working. Do you know why?

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldye5qg8/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <a class="active" href="">Item 1</a>
    <a href="">Item 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
a{text-decoration:none;}

.nav{
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
}

.nav a{
  padding: 15px;  
}

.nav .active{
  border-color:yellow;
  padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397370/change-link-color-of-the-current-page-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Hope it will work

EDIT: I used 5px bottom color in `.nav`. So, the whole `.nav` will use 5px bottom color. Then I used 5px in `.nav a.active` bottom color. The `.nav a.active` bottom color will be shown but on different lines. Hence I used `margin-bottom: -5px` to overlap `.nav` color.

```css
.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
}
.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.nav a.active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
    margin-bottom: -5px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <a class="active" href="">Item 1</a>
    <a href="">Item 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to add a yellow border bottom on hover? Like this doesn't work ".nav a:hover{
    border-color:yellow;
}"?

Comment: It is more helpful to explain the code and why any changes were made rather than simply saying "Try this".

Comment: @Jack please don't ask new questions in the comments of answers. If you have further questions, ask new questions to cover them.

Comment: If I mean, you want to know how to set a bottom yellow color on hover? 
If yes. put it                                                                                                              
.nav a.active:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
    margin-bottom: -5px
}

Comment: Thanks but also don't works: https://jsfiddle.net/r27wo830/.

Comment: @Jack use a different color on hover. https://jsfiddle.net/x0j7r8es/

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav .active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
    padding: 20px 20px 1px 20px;
}
```

is not the same element, you need to bring for him border-style also to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Just change border color to border-bottom like this

```
.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
}
```