# how to turn active <a> tag color into another color?

Tags: html, css, tags, anchor

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
}
a:link::before {
  color: grey;
}
a:visited,
a::after,
a:active{
  color: #00b39b;
  text-decoration: #00b39b;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="header-ul">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Career</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Departments</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

ok guys I wanna change only the active link color into this (#00b39b)
i tried different things like the :
1- a:active
2- a:visited
3- a:focus
4- a:hover
but I can't make to set only the active link to the color I want
any suggestions !!??

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML/CSS

Comment: You define `:active` correctly as per the CSS spec, but then you say you are trying to use `:visited`. This doesn't really make sense. Do you have some definition of "active" that is different to CSS's? You should probably tell us what that definition is.

Comment: Is this *yet another* duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397370/change-link-color-of-the-current-page-with-css ?

Comment: When posting a question, you really should provide some of your code so that we can get a better idea of the problem. Do all the links have the same `href` value? That would explain why they all change to the `:visited` color after you click on only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Now this code will change `a:active` color to `#00b39b`
`text-decoration` don't apply for color

Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text_decoration.asp) to know more about `text-decoration`

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
}

a:link::before {
  color: grey;
}

a:visited,
a::after,
a:active {
  color: #00b39b;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header-ul">
  <li>
    <a href="#">About us</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Career</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Departments</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```